# Pdf files not getting download in intel xdk app

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, intel-xdk

In intel xdk i use window.open("url of website") and  The website opens inside intel xdk app but the website contains lots of pdf links which are not getting downloaded even they are not getting clicked. Please help me what code shall i use so that any link will get download and to load every page it shows loader or processing.

Comment: Did you find the way to fix this problem, bro?

Comment: No @mr neo.please help me to solve this issue

Comment: `window.open(link_url, '_system' ,'location=yes');`. this code work for me

Comment: Downloading files inside website ?

Comment: Yes, files are inside website

Comment: Ok sir let me try and then i will get back to you